# Checkbox sortiing and Pagination not working toegther in codeigniter.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

we are trying to do ajax pagination and check-box sorting in our front page..

**step 1:** whenever click on the first checkbox it sends the ajax request and also one perameter to query from database and shows the result..

**Step2:** when we again checked the other checkbox , the without the page reloading the ajax request is gone and display record...
    - in step1:- checkword='cardiologist' (working fine)
    - in step2:- checkword='cardiologist','nephrologist' (showing duplicate values from cardiologist)
but the issue here is that pagging preserves the both perameter..
 when we click on the pagging class link it sends both ajax requests one after another.. that spoils the data fetching from database...
 but here we require only one perameter.. i.e second one as "checkword=cardiologist,nephrologist".

Thank all in advance for help

Comment: please show your code little bit

Comment: Thank you sandeep see code below.

Comment: http://ge.tt/1z7Nvv82/v/0?c